# Click event processes but watir-webdriver / selenium-webdriver still throws a TimeoutError on faster Macs

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

Gems in use:

- watir-webdriver-0.6.2
- selenium-webdriver-2.27.2

Using Firefox 16.0.2 on all systems.

Situation:
We have a modal window that closes after we run

```
link(:text, 'Continue').click
```

System 1:
Hardware Overview:

- Model Name:          MacBook Air
- Model Identifier:    MacBookAir4,2
- Processor Name:  Intel Core i5
- Processor Speed: 1.7 GHz
- Number of Processors:1
- Total Number of Cores: 2
- Memory: 4 GB
- OS: OS X 10.8.2

System 1 Result: Always succeeds

System 2:

- Model Name: MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier:     MacBookPro10,1
- Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
- Processor Speed:  2.3 GHz
- Number of Processors: 1
- Total Number of Cores: 4
- Memory: 16 GB
- OS: OS X 10.8.2

System 2 Results: Executes the click and then after the specified time throws a Timeout::Error.

A Middle system (sorry I don't have the full specs available) is a new Mac Mini also with Mountain Lion. This system WAS failing until while trying to track this down, I added a puts statement at the specific call that produced the timeout. This led, of course, to a constant success state, which indicated what we fondly call a Heisenerror.

The puts statement was added in the selenium-webdriver code in lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb around line 613 and looked like:

```
puts "-> #{verb.to_s.upcase} #{path}" if verb.to_s.upcase == 'POST'
```

This prints out all of the post requests made to the browser. The specific post request that timesout is one of the click requests. I don't have the full path, but will add it on Monday if it is required.

Does anybody know how to circumvent system-dependent timeouts with watir/selenium?

Comment: Have you tried using any of the wait methods mentioned on http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/?

Comment: Yes I have to the same result. See my comments below for what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use wait_until method for waiting loading page

```
wait_until(:timeout => 20) { page.current_url =~ /some_url/ }
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/moredip/Frank/master/Frank/Cucumber/WaitHelper.wait_until

and then

```
find(".some_class").find('a', :text => /Continue/).click
```

Comment: There isn't a change in URL to wait for. So instead I did a 
    wait_until (timeout: 30) { 
        link(text: 'Continue').present? && link(text: 'Continue').visible? 
    }
    link(text: 'Continue').click

Same result.